# Creating an object from a black and white image

Tags: vertices

I would like to map the vertices of a shape to the pixel of an image. The mapping result will modify the position on the Z-axis of the vertex.

For example:

1. the pixel at position X=0, Y=0 is white (255 or 1): so the vertex will be positioned at (0,0,1000)
2. the pixel at position X=0, Y=1 is gray (128 or 0.5): so the vertex will be positioned at (0,1,500)
3. the pixel at position X=20, Y=180 is dark (22 or 0.*** ): so the vertex will be positioned at (20,180,***)

Is this possible?
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do this per-vertex (without using python), but you can do this with a heavily subdivided mesh and a displacement modifier. Is something like this satisfactory?

(Just to explain the image - I used the same texture as both the basis for the Displacement Modifier as well as the Material so the areas that are being "elevated" by their color value are colored accordingly)

[image: Displace]

Comment: I would suggest to do this with a displacement modifier instead and not on a shader, so that you could add a decimate modifer to the stack, to reduce the number of vertices. The subdivision could also be done with a subdivision modifier, in simple mode, as the first modifier on the stack.